# EF complex class getting me null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class like this.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IList<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is that when I pass user as parameter to a repository layer method Branch property appears in null. I've verified that before it arrives to the repository it's not null. I think is something with serialization, but i'dont know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

This is the way the repository get objects:

```
public readonly IDbSet<T> DbSet;
public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string sortColumn = null, bool sortDirection = true, params  string[] includes)
    {
        if (sortColumn == null)
        {
            var resultSet = GetDbSet(includes).Where(predicate);
            resultSet.ForEachAsync(e => Detach(e)).Wait();
            return resultSet;
        }
        else
            return OrderByField<T>(GetDbSet(includes).Where(predicate), sortColumn, sortDirection);
    }
    private IQueryable<T> GetDbSet(params string[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> resultSet = DbSet;

        foreach (string include in includes)
            resultSet = resultSet.Include(include);

        return resultSet;
    }

    private T Detach(T entity)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Contracts.Contract.Requires(entity != null);

        var entry = Context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
        return entity;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where to fetch the object and how you pass it.

Comment: I think it's no something with the repository, if I save it to a Session variable I have de same problem.

Comment: I cannot help you if you do not show the code where you fetch the object from the rep.

Comment: There I've added the generic repository that i use to get instances. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the actual code you've wrote to fetch the objects and how you pass them to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it. The problem was on generic repository i've been working with. When it gets entries set the entries as Detached and that resulted on nulls when I passed to the repository to save. I've remove the detach method and everything is working.